# Sum of $1^2+3^2+\cdots+(2n+1)^2$ Have trouble with proof.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been working through a question on Courant's What is Mathematics?

This is the question: Prove $1^2+3^2+\cdots+(2n+1)^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3)}{3}$. I called this $S_{(2n+1)^2}$.

What I've been given as a hint is that I can use the sum $1+2^2+3^2+\cdots+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ (I called this $S_{n^2}$) in some way.

So here's my line of thought:

What do I need to do to $S_{n^2}=1^2+2^2+3^2+\cdots+n^2$ to get $S_{(2n+1)^2}=1^2+3^2+\cdots+(2n+1)^2$?

When I compared them, I thought that $S_{n^2}-(2^2+4^2+\cdots+(2n)^2) = S_{(2n+1)^2}$.

I defined $2^2+4^2+\cdots+(2n)^2$ as $S_{(2n)^2}$.

After a bit of head-scratching I managed to figure out $S_{(2n)^2}=2^2(0)+2^2(1)^2+2^2(2)^2+\cdots+2^2(n)^2=4(1^2+2^2+3^2+\cdots+n^2)=4S_{n^2} =\frac{2}{3}n(n+1)(2n+1)$

Now is where my confusion starts. So from my logic above I went forward with $S_{n^2}-S_{(2n)^2}=S_{(2n+1)^2}$ which gave me $-\frac{1}{2}(n(n+1)(2n+1))$ which isn't $S_{(2n+1)^2}$.

I don't know where I really went wrong. One of my main suspicions is that $S_{n^2}-S_{(2n)^2}=S_{n^2}-4S_{n^2}=-3S_{n^2}\neq S_{(2n+1)^2}$. But I don't see why.

Comment: Proof by induction may be more appropriate since you are already told what the result will be.

Comment: You're making matters worse for yourself with inconsistent use of $S_k$. First it's the sum of the squares of the odd numbers below $k$, the you start using it for the sum of the squares of all numbers below $k$. Try using different names and see if you can get through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a misleading notation. Let
$$
Q_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=1^2+2^2+\dots+n^2={n(n+1)(2n+1)\over6},
$$
so that
$$
Q_{2n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} k^2=1^2+2^2+\dots+(2n)^2+(2n+1)^2={(2n+1)(2n+2)(4n+3)\over6}.
$$
As you noticed:
$$
1^2+3^2+\dots+(2n-1)^2+(2n+1)^2=Q_{2n+1}-4Q_n={(n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3)\over3}.
$$

Comment: Could you please express your first two sums in sigma-notation form? I believe it will help me further clarify where I went wrong. Many thanks.

Comment: I've just added the definitions of $Q_n$ and $Q_{2n+1}$ using the summation symbol. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much; it really cleared up where I went wrong.

Answer (score 6):

**Very easy proof**

$$\sum_{k=1}^n(2k+1)^2=4\sum_{k=1}^n k^2+4\sum_{k=1}^nk+\sum_{k=1}^n1.$$
Using your hint, you can very easily conclude.

Comment: Shouldn't there be 4 lots of the sum of K when you expand the quadratic?

Comment: @george $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$..

Comment: indeed for a+b but isn't it $(2a+b)^2$

Comment: @george: you right, i corrected it.

Answer (score 6):

$$1^2+2^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot+n^2=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

This leads to the following:

> $$1^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot+n^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot+(2n+1)^2=\dfrac{(2n+1)(2n+1+1)(2(2n+1)+1)}{6}$$
>
> $$2^2+4^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot+(2n)^2=2^2(1^2+2^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot+n^2)=4\cdot\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

Thus,

> $$1^2+3^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot+(2n+1)^2=\dfrac{(2n+1)(2n+1+1)(2(2n+1)+1)}{6}-\quad4\cdot\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}=\dfrac{(n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3)}{3}=\sum_{i=0}^n (2i+1)^2$$

Note: You have an extra $n$ in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $S_k$ denote the sum of the first $k$ squares. You should know a formula for this. Now

$$1^2+3^2+\cdots+(2n+1)^2$$
$$= (1^2+2^2+\cdots+(2n+2)^2)-(2^2+4^2+\cdots+(2n+2)^2)$$
$$=(1^2+2^2+\cdots+(2n+2)^2)-2^2(1^2+2^2+\cdots+(n+1)^2)$$
$$=S_{2n+2}-4S_{n+1}$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Using your hint, here is one way to go:

$$1^2 + 3^2 +\cdots +(2n+1)^2 = (1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2+\cdots +(2n+1)^2) - (2^2 + 4^2 + 6^2+\cdots+ (2n)^2)\\
(1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2+\cdots+ (2n+1)^2) - 4(1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2+\cdots+ n^2)$$

$$\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)(4n+3)}{6} - \frac{4(n)(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

Alternatively, you could use a proof by induction.

Base case:

$$n = 1\\
1^2 + 3^2 = \frac {1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot5}{3} = 10$$

Suppose:

$$1^2+3^2+\cdots+(2n+1)^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3)}{3}$$

We will show that:

$$1^2+3^2+\cdots+(2n+1)^2 + (2n+3)^2=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(2n+3)(2n+5)}{3}$$

By our hypothesis:

$$\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3)}{3} + (2n+3)^2=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(2n+3)(2n+5)}{3}$$

And simplify.